# Using REGEXP_LIKE with mulltiple conditions to match patterns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Table  Name : test
Column_Name: ID
Correct format for column ID - '^\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d1}$'

Conditions:
Must match above pattern but must not start with 15, numbers from 2-8 , 00, 000 , 0000.

Using REGEXP_LIKE to match the condition specified, but unable to include the start with scenarios in a single REGEXP_LIKE:

```
with test as (
select  '0614-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0014-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0004-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0000-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '00120792-2..' ID from dual union all
select  '0614- 210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0614210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '2614-210297-103-6' ID from dual
)        
select
case
    when regexp_like(ID, '^\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d{1}$') 
        then ID
    else
        case
            when regexp_count(ID, '\d') = 14
                then
                    case
                        when
                            not regexp_like(ID,'^15|^2-8|^00|^000|^0000')
                        then ID
                    end
            else ID
        end
end ID_tr
from test
```

Comment: Just FYI: `1}` is a typo. You can use `'^\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d$'`, as `{1}` is always redundant.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Corrected the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way to simplify your condition, even if not in a single regexp:

```
regexp_like(ID, '^[190]\d{3}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d$') and
substr(ID, 1, 2) not in ('00', '15')
```

Here I use `^[190]\d{3}` instead of `^\d{4}` to only match if the first digit is not in 2-8;
the only way I found to avoid strings starting with 15 or 00, 000, 0000 is by checking the first two characters with a `substr`.

With your data, this

```
select ID,
    case
     when regexp_like(ID, '^[190]\d{3}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d$') and
          substr(ID, 1, 2) not in ('00', '15') then ID
    end as result
from test
```

gives:

```
ID                 RESULT            
------------------ ------------------
0614-210297-103-6  0614-210297-103-6 
0014-210297-103-6                    
0004-210297-103-6                    
0000-210297-103-6                    
00120792-2..                         
0614- 210297-103-6                   
0614210297-103-6                     
2614-210297-103-6
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "must not start with 15, numbers from 2-8 , 00, 000 , 0000".

You can simplify that to: must not start with 00, 15, 2n through 8n.

Or you could be positive instead of negative: must start with 01 through 09, or 10 through 14 or 16 through 19 or 9n.

With positive conditions you can get one REGEXP:

```
with test(id) as (
select  '0614-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0014-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0004-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0000-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '00120792-2..' ID from dual union all
select  '0614- 210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '0614210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '1514-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '1614-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '2614-210297-103-6' ID from dual union all
select  '9614-210297-103-6' ID from dual
)      
select id from test
where regexp_like(id,'^(0[1-9]|1[1-46-9]|9\d)\d{2}-\d{6}-\d{3}-\d$')

ID
0614-210297-103-6
1614-210297-103-6
9614-210297-103-6
```